# Normalization into Third Normal form

Tags: normalization

```
T(A,B,C) A-->B
A-->C 
C--->A 
C-->B Which normal form is the table?

  convert it into 3nf

 A is the key 
Please explain the answer 
thanks
 i was told it is in 3nf, but there is a transitive dependency .. how can it         be in 3nf?
```

I guess i'VE GIVEN ENOUGH DETAILS
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Where did the E attribute come from ?

Answer (score 1):

The transitive dependency doesn't matter for 3NF.  All that matters is that all nonprime attributes (the ones which are not part of any key) are, somewhat loosely speaking, dependent exclusively upon a key.

The keys are {A} and {C}.  The nonprime attributes are {B}.  B doesn't depend on anything else than A and/or C.  Ergo 3NF.  At least (I haven't bothered to check whether it is also BCNF).

EDIT

For BCNF as well, the "transitive dependencies" do not matter.  What is needed for BCNF is that all applicable dependencies are out of a superkey (i.e. have a superkey on their LHS) or else are trivial.  For that not to be the case here, there would have to be an FD that has B (or nothing at all, but that's an "exotic" edge case) on its LHS but neither A nor C.  The only applicable FD that satisfies this is B->B, but that one is trivial.  BCNF allows "transitive dependencies", just so long as they merely link attributes of one key to attributes of another one.  In fact, if there are multiple keys in a schema, there MUST be such "transitive dependencies".  If your professor uses the term "3NF" (inappropriately so) when he means "BCNF", then it doesn't surprise me he also uses the term "transitive dependencies" (already somewhat vague and sloppy in its own right) when what he means is probably something like "dependencies to which the rule of transitivity can be applied AND that have nonkey attributes in their 'connecting parts' somewhere somehow".

Comment: Whenever my professor says to put it into 3NF, we are supposed to put into BCNF,,by default. Hence we were told that here should be no transitive dependencies in 3NF. Could you please explain the answer again, if we were asked to put into BCNF.? Thank you.